# parseInt misbehaves when passed as argument to a map call

Tags: javascript

Why is this happening?

```
var numbers = [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ];
var intNumbers = numbers.map( parseInt ); // intNumbers = [1, NaN, NaN, NaN]
var fltNumbers = numbers.map( parseFloat ); // fltNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

But `Array.prototype.map.call( numbers, parseInt );` returns `[ 1, 2, 3, 4];`. I'm running this code in Google Chrome 26.0.1410.65.

Comment: explained at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: also simple fix: `numbers.map( function(i) { return parseInt(i) })`

Comment: Also, don't forget to *always* pass the radix parameter to `parseInt()` and set it to `10` if you're using base 10, because, otherwise, you're likely to encounter strange and very hard to debug issues later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link to proper answer is given in comments, but i want to post it here
:

> ```
> ["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt);
> ```
>
> While one could expect `[1, 2, 3]`
>
> The actual result is `[1, NaN, NaN]`
>
> parseInt is often used with one argument, but takes two. The second
>   being the radix To the callback function, Array.prototype.map passes 3
>   arguments: the element, the index, the array

The third argument is ignored by parseInt, but not the second one, hence the possible confusion.

Quick fix

```
function returnInt(element){
   return parseInt(element,10);
}


["1", "2", "3"].map(returnInt);
```

Actual result is an array of numbers (as expected)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-GB/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map explains how map works.

I find it easier with the solution that jonah proposed, create a returning function for thing you want to map instead of tossing it..

```
intN = numbers.map(function(i) { return parseInt(i) });
```

The real reason is that you are trying to feed a function to map, but JS is not getting the function properly.

You better declare the function first and then feed it.

```
var titi = function(i) { return parseInt(i); };

var intN2 = numbers.map(titi);
```

Comment: There's no need to declare the function in advance. You only need to not use `parseInt` directly.